# Configure Arduino IDE to not quit when the last sketch is closed

Tags: arduino-ide

The Arduino app takes a long time to launch on MacOS. (The `Initializing Packages...` stage takes over a minute.) It's very frustrating when you accidentally close the last sketch window and the app quits. Then you have to wait for it launch again.

Is there anything that can be done to stop it from closing automatically?

Comment: no, it's a single-document-interface (one app instance per sketch), so there's no "basket" to keep around like with multiple-document interfaces such as photoshop, notepad++, excel, etc

Comment: But opening additional documents happens instantly. You don't have that slow launch experience until after you close the last document.

Comment: It used to warn you when you tried to do that, I don't know why that warning was removed.

Comment: yes, some of the background processes, notably java, are shared between instances, so the first one is slower. You can try using some tool to hide the first instance so it can't be closed. on windows there was an app called "process control" which allowed that, not sure about mac...